# Microsoft 365: Access 2016: Validation rule: Number Data Type: No decimals

Tags: validation, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'd like to know what validation rule I would want to write if I want to prevent the inclusion of decimals in my number field.

If possible, I'd like to do this *only* in the validation rule line in Design View, and not have to touch VBA.

I've tried other exclusion validation rules but they don't work with Access 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substract the integer portion to get only the decimals, and test if that's 0, in a field-level validation rule e.g.:

```
MyField - Int(MyField) = 0
```

However, you could also just store your values as a *Long Integer*, making it impossible to store decimal values because they just don't fit in there.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither solution is working. I've attached a screenshot of how my current table is looking on the design view. 

What happens when I type in a decimal into the field of a new record, it automatically rounds itself rather than keeping the decimal and violating the validation rule as a result.Unfortunately, neither solution is working. I've attached a screenshot of how my current table is looking on the design view. The record rounds itself to an integer (I just want decimals to be impossible to input).
https://prnt.sc/jun9h7

Comment: Never mind, I had to change the Field Size to "Single" in the General tab in design view in order to prevent rounding.